# cs50 finance project: lookup() not returning dictionary

Tags: python, flask, cs50

while implementing `buy()` function, I need to use a dictionary returned from `lookup(symbol)` function found in `helpers.py` and access it in `app.py`. But it seems like it's not returning any data. the code is below.

```
# in helper.py
```

```
   """
   Decorate routes to require login.
   https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/viewdecorators/
   """
   @wraps(f)
   def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
       if session.get("user_id") is None:
           return redirect("/login")
       return f(*args, **kwargs)
   return decorated_function


def lookup(symbol):
   """Look up quote for symbol."""

   # Contact API
   try:
       api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY")
       response = requests.get(f"https://cloud-sse.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{urllib.parse.quote_plus(symbol)}/quote?token={api_key}")
       response.raise_for_status()
   except requests.RequestException:
       return None

   # Parse response
   try:
       quote = response.json()
       return {
           "name": quote["companyName"],
           "price": float(quote["latestPrice"]),
           "symbol": quote["symbol"]
       }
   except (KeyError, TypeError, ValueError):
       return None
```

and the code in app.py is

```
def buy():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("buy.html")

    else:
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        shares = request.form.get("share_num")
        result = lookup(symbol)


        cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
        if cash < result["price"] * request.form.get("share_num"):
            return apology("insufficient balance",403)
        db.execute("INSERT INTO stock(symbol,name,quantity,price) VALUES (?,?,?,?) WHERE users.id = stock.user_id AND id= ?",
                   result["symbol"], result["name"], request.form.get("share_num"),result["price"],session["user_id"])
        db.execute("UPDATE users(cash) SET (?) WHERE users.id = stock.user_id AND id=? ",
                   cash - result["price"] * request.form.get("share_num"), session["user_id"])
        return redirect("/")
```

and html code is

```
{% block title %}
    buy stock
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/buy" method="post">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control mx-auto w-auto"  name="symbol" placeholder="symbol" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" name="share_num" placeholder="quantity" type="number">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">buy</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

the error am getting is

```
File "/workspaces/89966944/finance/helpers.py", line 33, in decorated_function
return f(*args, **kwargs)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/workspaces/89966944/finance/app.py", line 64, in buy
  if cash < result["price"] * request.form.get("share_num"):
          ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You can try to change one of your responses from lookup function to know which except block it enter. Ex: let first exception returns None and second returns {}. Depending on the error, you will know where is the problem

Comment: @Magaren  I guess the problem is contacting API. Because I changed first exception to {} and it gave me this error ` File "/workspaces/89966944/finance/app.py", line 64, in buy if cash < result['price'] * request.form.get("share_num"): ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^ KeyError: 'price' `

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that you are trying to reach for a key in a None object.

In this case, `result` is None and you are trying to execute `result["price"]`, which triggers the `TypeError`.

Be aware that the `lookup` function can return `None` if:

- There is a connection problem with the API (the first try except is responsible for checking this)
- The API returns a response that is not a dictionary. I can happen if you input a symbol that does not exist, for example. (the second try except is responsible for this)

You have to check if `lookup` returns `None` before calling `result["price"]` to avoid getting `KeyErrors`. For example:

```py
result = lookup(symbol)
if result is None:
    # Do something if lookup returns None
```

Be sure to call your API using your browser to check what kind for data it is returning.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I have called my API on browser and it is returning a dictionary which indicates the problem is connecting to the API. Any idea How can I solve connection problem please?

Comment: CS50 uses IEX's API and once you register, it can used for only 30 days for free. Check out if this is the case.